Can a man go against the order of his parents?
Can a man go against the order of his parents, if he doesn't like the order
Can a man defy the order of his mother and father  ?

mostly one should NOT go against parents order but in very very extreme cases yes like Prahalada..Prahlad’s (who didn’t obey his father Hiranayakashipu) character seems to be more moral than Meghnadh (who obeyed his father Ravana)…

The one and only order of one's parents (or even a Guru) which can be defied is marriage i.e., if the person wants to be a brahmachari and attain Moksa in one lifetime. This defiance incurs no sin. And of course, any dharmic order can be freely rejected (e.g., unnecessary meat consumption, stealing, etc.)

According to Manu Smriti one must always obey their parents. Se the verses given below:

Manu smriti 2.227. That trouble (and pain) which the parents undergo
on the birth of (their) children, cannot be compensated even in a
hundred years.
2.228. Let him always do what is agreeable to those (two) and always (what may please) his teacher; when those three are pleased, he
obtains all (those rewards which) austerities (yield).
2.230. For they are declared to be the three worlds, they the three (principal) orders, they the three Vedas, and they the three sacred
fires
2.232. He who neglects not those three, (even after he has become) a householder, will conquer the three worlds and, radiant in body like a
god, he will enjoy bliss in heaven.
2.235. As long as those three live, so long let him not (independently) perform any other (meritorious acts);let him always
serve them, rejoicing (to do what is) agreeable and beneficial (to
them).


Does this mean that children are bound to obey even the adharmic commands of parents ? And how Prahlada's disobeying his father fits in this ?

What is stated here is the general rule or law but exceptions might arise in case of some specific examples like the ones you've mentioned @অনু

Whether a man (or anyone) can go against the orders of their parents depends on a few factors:

Age and Independence: If the man is an adult and financially independent, he has more freedom to make his own choices, even if they differ from his parents' wishes.
Cultural Context: In some cultures, strong emphasis is placed on filial piety, meaning respect and obedience to parents. In others, independence is encouraged at a younger age.
Nature of the Order: If the order is abusive or controlling, there's a stronger case for defying it. However, if it's a disagreement about career paths or relationships, navigating a compromise might be a better approach.

Here are some things to consider:

Communication: Talking openly and honestly with parents can sometimes bridge the gap. Explaining your reasons and finding common ground can be more productive than outright defiance.
Respect: Even if you disagree, showing respect for your parents' opinions is important.
Consequences: There might be strained relationships or financial repercussions if you go against their wishes. Weighing the potential outcomes is crucial.

Ultimately, the decision rests with the individual. It's a balancing act between respecting your parents and living your own life.
